# Installing PHP in windows - "php.exe" and "PHP SAPI" both should support pdo_mysql

Tags: php, wamp

We use Windows for our development systems. I am installing PHP, Apache, MySQL manually. All from zip packages. Now:

If I use php *thread safe* binaries:
pdo_mysql fails to load when executing php.exe from command line. I get the following warning:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=0
PHP    compiled with module API=20060613, debug=0, thread-safety=1
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked our RHEL production server, there php thready safety is disabled. So I downloaded not thread safe binaries [from here](https://www.php.net/get/php-5.2.10-nts-Win32.zip/from/a/mirror).

Now, I hit another problem: Apache is failing to start. The error.log says:

```
[Thu Mar 04 13:54:08 2010] [crit] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP.
Pre-configuration failed
[Thu Mar 04 13:54:08 2010] [warn] (OS 995)The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.  : winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
```

How do I install php with support for pdo_mysql in Windows? So, that the command line php.exe works?

Note: In the thread-safe binary, although php.exe was not loading pdo_mysql, the PHP API was able to load it. Because in phpinfo, it was appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry! It was stupid.
I figured out this was the problem:
Apache was using the thread-safe SAPI. The command line was using the php.exe supplied by Zend Core!

I reconfigured the "PATH" environment variable: so now it points to the php.exe in the thread safe package. Issues solved.